# How to use the Plugins in a vue-chartjs chart?

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I'm using vue-chartjs for my Vue3 app, and I don't really understand how the Plugins work.

I took the BarChart example from the documentation, **available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/apertureless/vue-chartjs/tree/main/sandboxes/bar)**

So, in *barChart.ts* (line 5 to 14), there are some Plugin imports: "**Title**", "**Legend**", etc
Now, I wanted a Title, so I added this code on line 77

```
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                padding: {
                    top: 10,
                    bottom: 30
                },
                text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
            },
            subtitle: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Custom Chart Subtitle'
            }
        }
```

It seems to works fine... but if I had a Legend,

```
legend: {
   display: true,
   position: 'bottom',
   title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Test legend'
   }
},
```

it gives me an error on the Bar in the return function :

```
No overload matches this call.
 The last overload gave the following error.
 Argument of type 'TypedChartComponent<"bar", number[], unknown>' is not assignable to 
 parameter of type 'DefineComponent<{ chartData: { labels: string[]; datasets: ...
 ...
 runtime-core.d.ts(928, 25): The last overload is declared here.
```

How can I add this Plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the type explicitly should get rid of the type error.

```js
import {
  ChartOptions
} from "chart.js";

const chartOptions: ChartOptions<"bar"> = { /* ... */ };
```

Here's [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-christian-jtwxqy?file=/src/components/barChart.ts).

Comment: That worked perfectly, I marked the answer as "Accepted" !